# Can I say “bypass the building”?

Tags: direction

One day at a bus stop near my office, a person asked me how to reach a shopping mall that is nearby. Since there recently is a new building site besides the bus stop, we cannot see the shopping mall directly from the bus stop. But It is just behind the new building site. 
What is the best expression to give direction? Should I say “You should bypass the building site.”?

Comment: Depending on your geography, "bypass" may have different meanings. I suggest "_Go past_ the building site."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say, “Go past the building site.”  Or, “Go around,” or “Go by.”  Personally, from your description, I would say, “Go around” since it sounds like the construction site is directly between you and the desired location.

Bypass means something similar but would sound awkward.  Sometimes, phrasing can be technically correct but sound off.

Good luck!

Note:  I am a native American English speaker.  British English speakers may have a different opinion.

Comment: I like “go around”. Actually going around by either ways can reach that shopping mall. Thanks for the help!